# Funky css is adding a bottom padding/margin

Tags: css

I cannot figure out why my css is creating this funky bottom margin or border I took a little video so you can see it: http://img.zobgib.com/2011-04-25_1317.swf  The margin/border doesn't show except when the page is resized to pretty small.  My css is pretty standard, and I have not inline styling or JS styling that would cause it. What would cause this weird margin?

Here is my CSS

```
html {


}
body {
}

#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

#drawn {
    background: #fff !important;

}

#content > * {
}

#toolcontainer {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 50px;
    min-width: 940px;
}

#toolcontainer > * {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;  
}

#slidescontainer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 52px;
    width: 130px;
    min-height: 658px;
}
#newslide {
    background: url(/static/img/new_slide.png) !important; 
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
#slidescontainer canvas {
    position: relative;
}
#slidescontainer > * {
    height: 80px;
    width: 106px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #000;

}

#container {
    position: absolute;
    min-height:608px;
    min-width: 810px;
/*  height: 608px;
    width: 810px;*/
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    top: 52px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0px;
    left: 132px;
    background: #d5d5d5;
    border: 10px solid #000;
}

#container canvas {
/*  left: 50%;
    margin-left: -405px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -304px;*/
}

#debug {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: black;
    color: #34e338;
    z-index: 50;
}

canvas {
    position: absolute;
}

#colorSelector {
    position: relative;
    width: 46px;
    height: 46px;
}

#colorSelector div {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    background: #000000;
    width: 46px;
    height: 46px;
}
```

Comment: Is that border always there, or just there after you bring up firebug?

Comment: It is there when I bring up firebug or make the window "short" also when I remove the min-height it doubles in size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the min-height in #container to 638px.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a lot of browser-specific CSS, and it looks like you were accessing it in an unsupported browser (Firefox doesn't support Microsoft markup, for obvious reasons). I'd recommend trying CSS3 selectors and rules instead of the browser-specific rules.

Comment: I never use the .shaddow so that can actually be removed

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `style = "overflow:hidden"` to your `html` tag like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  style = "overflow:hidden">
```

If it is an issue with page height, that may clear it up